# is there any way to find out which endpoints are triggered on a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, google-analytics

I have a generic implementation to fire a `page_view` google analytics event in my react application every time there's a route change:

```js
const usePageViewTracking = () => {
  const { pathname, search, hash } = useLocation();
  const pathnameWithTrailingSlash = addTrailingSlashToPathname(pathname) + search + hash;

  useEffect(() => {
    invokeGAPageView(pathnameWithTrailingSlash);
  }, [pathname]);
};

export default usePageViewTracking;
```

This works fine, but I need to fire ga4 `page_view` events with custom dimensions and if the page doesn't have some data, I should not send it in page_view event.

I turned my previous code into this:

```js
const usePageViewTracking = () => {
  const { pathname, search, hash } = useLocation();

  const subscriptionsData = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state?.[REDUX_API.KEY]?.[REDUX_API.SUBSCRIPTIONS]?.successPayload?.data
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    sendPageViewEvent({ subscriptionsData });
  }, [pathname, subscriptionsData]);

};

export default usePageViewTracking;
```

`sendPageViewEvent` is where I collect most of the information I need to be sent, and currently is like this:

```js
export const sendPageViewEvent = ({ subscriptionsData }: SendPageViewEventProps): void => {
  const { locale, ga } = window.appData;
  const { subscriptions, merchants, providers } =
    prepareSubscriptionsData({ subscriptionsData }) || {};

  const events = {
    page_lang: locale || DEFAULT_LOCALE,
    experiment: ga.experiment,
    consent_status: Cookies.get(COOKIES.COOKIE_CONSENT) || 'ignore',
    ...(subscriptionsData && {
      ucp_subscriptions: subscriptions,
      ucp_payment_providers: providers,
      ucp_merchants: merchants,
    }),
  };

  sendGA4Event({ eventType: GA4_EVENT_TYPE.PAGE_VIEW, ...events });
};
```

So as you can see, I have some dimensions that are always sent, and some that are conditionally sent (subscriptionsData).

**The problem**

The problem with this implementation is that once the page renders, it waits for subscriptionData to be available to fire the event, which would be ok, if this data would be fetched in all pages. If a page doesn't have this data, I still need to send the event, just not attach subscriptions dimensions into it.

I tried different approaches in my application, like:

1. going to each page and firing it individually, but since it's a huge application, it would require a huge refactoring that turns out to not to be justified for analytics purposes.❌
2. Having some sort of config file to define which routes fire which endpoints, but this is a terrible and unmaintainable idea ❌

Now if there would be a way to know based on the redux store how figure out which endpoints are being triggered on a page, maybe I could then detect it and decide if I should wait for this property to be available or fire the event without it.

PS: there will be more fetched data from different endpoints that I'll have to fire on `page_view` experiment too... and it's an SPA aplication (so everything is using CSR).

Any ideas are welcome! :D

Comment: Sorry but can't you do a simple `if` condition check to see if `subscriptionsData` exist or not and do accordingly?

Comment: that's the thing @ShivamJha ... "accordingly" would be if there's data to be fetched or not... because if I simply add a condition, what will happen is that I'll have 2 page_view events fired for a page that has subscription data. It will fire first without it, and then once store is populated, it'll fire again.. two `page_view` events when the user rendered the page only once (from his perspective, of course - which is what the data should represent)